# Did UITableViewDelegate affects tableViews row height?

Tags: ios, swift

i'll set the UITableViewDelegate on a tableView, but if i do so the row height changes: 
The 1st pic is without delegation; the 2nd with delegation (btw. missing service 1 is correct)

[image: without delegation]

[image: with delegation]

the code for row height:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if cellSubTitle.count == 0 {
        return 70
    } else {
        if cellSubTitle[indexPath.row] == "" {
            return 70
        } else {
            return 88
        }
    }
}
```

and for the tableView:

```
private lazy var tableView: StandardTV = {
    let tv = StandardTV()

    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.headerType = .none
    tv.cellTitle = ["Service 2", "Service 3", "Service 4", "Service 5", "Service 6", "Service 7"]
//        tv.delegate = self

    return tv
}()
```

i hope someone could help me :)

**EDIT**

the rowForHeight-Code is part of a TableView-Class ("StandardTV"). This class has is own delegate.

```
 class StandardTV: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)

        delegate = self
        dataSource = self

        backgroundColor = .white
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        separatorStyle = .none

        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

         self.register(StandardTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
     }
    ....
}
```

The second code snippet comes from the view controller where i insert the tableView.

Comment: You implement the `heightForRowAt` and you wonder why the height changes? That's the point of that delegate method.

Comment: Without delegation, the tableView won't ask it's delegate the row of the height in the function heightForRowAt... so yes, the behavior won't be the same.

Comment: @maddy thanks for the hint. my fault was to use the delegate twice. Insert the delegate in my code above, will be the second time and i suppose that it'll "override" the first delegate?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to the hint of @maddy and @Swift Rabbit i got an answer: Yes, of cource affects the delegate the row height :) 
i had implemented the delegate methode for the tableView twice. One in my "StandardTV"-class and the second one on the viewController. Therefore i suppose that the first delegate at my "StandardTV"-class will be ignored and so the row height.

btw: i use these "StandardTV"-class within different viewController and want to keep the same row height.